# Why does the kubernetes-vault init container need to unwrap the secret id supplied by the controller?

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

In the diagram on the `kubernetes-vault` repo, you can see that the init container takes the wrapped `secret_id` and the unwraps and redeems the `secret_id` for a token via Vault. Why doesn't the `kubernetes-vault` controller do this unwrapping and redemption itself and simply transmit the token to the init container?

https://github.com/Boostport/kubernetes-vault/raw/master/flow-diagram.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: The [kubernetes-vault](https://github.com/Boostport/kubernetes-vault) project is an open-source project maintained by my company.*

The reason the init container unwraps the secret is 2 fold:

- Only the init container and the pod it is in is able to see the final secret. That means that the kubernetes-vault controller does not know what the token is and is not able to use it for malicious purposes if compromised.
- If a someone intercepts the wrapped token and unwraps it, the init container would not be able to unwrap the token and this is a good signal that cluster has been compromised. If the unwrapped token is sent to the init container, it can be intercepted and it would not be possible to alert on this.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.

Comment: @F21 I don't quite figure out how Init Container is able to get a wrapped token. Which credentials it's using to request a wrapped token to Vault?

Comment: @Jordi The init container uses the `role_id` (which is set via an environment variable) and the `secret_id` which is pushed into the init container by the controller. The init container exchanges the `role_id` and `secret_id` for an auth token by sending those 2 pieces to Vault.

Comment: And which are the credentials used by controller?

Comment: The controller itself uses its own auth token to talk to Vault. In terms of working with the init container, it uses the `role` from the annotation on the init container and exchanges it for a `secret_id` using Vault. Note that the `role` and `role_id` are different things. For a complete picture, see: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Boostport/kubernetes-vault/master/flow-diagram.png